# How to convert a float to a string regardless of regional settings?

Tags: c++, mfc, formatting, locale

My product is targeted to a Portuguese audience where the comma is the decimal symbol. I usually use CString::Format to input numbers into strings, and it takes into account the computer's regional settings. While in general this is a good approach, I'm having problems in formatting SQL queries, for instance:

```
CString szInsert;
szInsert.Format("INSERT INTO Vertices (X, Y) VALUES (%f, %f)", pt.X, pt.Y);
```

When values are passed I get this string which is an incorrect query:

```
INSERT INTO Vertices (X, Y) VALUES (3,56, 4,67)
```

How do I enforce the dot as the decimal symbol in these strings, without changing the regional settings and without having to make specialized strings for each float value?

Note: this is intended as a general question, not a SQL one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did.

```
CString FormatQuery(LPCTSTR pszFormat, ...)
{
    CString szLocale = setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, NULL);
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "English");

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, pszFormat);
    CString szFormatted;
    int nSize = (_vscprintf(pszFormat, args) + 1) * sizeof(char);
    _vsnprintf_s(szFormatted.GetBuffer(nSize), nSize, nSize, pszFormat, args);
    szFormatted.ReleaseBuffer();
    va_end(args);

    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, szLocale);
    return szFormatted;
}
```

You should use it like `sprintf`. You must `#include <locale.h>` in order for it to work.

I'm a bit stubborn so I didn't use prepared statements/parametrized queries. If you have a similar problem, I suggest you do that. Meanwhile, if your problem is not SQL-related, my answer should help.

**Edit:** Here's a thread safe version:

```
CString FormatQuery(LPCTSTR pszFormat, ...)
{
    _locale_t locale = _create_locale(LC_NUMERIC, "English");

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, pszFormat);
    CString szFormatted;
    int nSize = (_vscprintf_l(pszFormat, locale, args) + 1) * sizeof(char);
    _vsnprintf_s_l(szFormatted.GetBuffer(nSize), nSize, nSize, pszFormat, locale, args);
    szFormatted.ReleaseBuffer();
    va_end(args);

    return szFormatted;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Bad idea, you really should be using prepared statements. It's not really trivial to do SQL injection with just numbers, but CString::Format is just not the correct way to do parameter binding.

(MFC and SQL has been a while - turns out this is bloody well hidden. I'm starting to see how we ended up with SQL injection bugs, thanks Microsoft. With raw ODBC you create a statement (once) with SQLPrepare. Pass ? for the 2 parameters you want to fill in. Subsequently, for each INSERT call `SQLBindParameter(stmt, 1, &X); SQLBindParameter(stmt, 2, &Y) /*extra parameters omitted, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710963(VS.85).aspx */`. Finally, call SQLExecute to preform the operation. )

Comment: Is there a way to do it with ADO?

Comment: ADO would be rather trivial - set the Prepared property on your Command object, and change the Parameters collection on ecacht INSERT

Answer (score 9):

A comment about Pukku's suggestion with ostringstream: For this to be locale-independent, one should explicitely imbue() the stream with the desired locale:

```
std::ostringstream s;
s.imbue(std::locale::classic());
s << "INSERT INTO Vertices (X, Y) VALUES (" << pt.X << ", " << pt.Y << ")";
```

Otherwise, the current global locale is used.

Answer (score 6):

Parameterized queries should avoid this issue altogether. You should look into those. That said, you should be able to use [setlocale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d.aspx) or similar to change the decimal separator.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
_create_locale( LC_NUMERIC, "C" )
```

to create an 'English' (C default) locale and then pass this to one of the _sprintf_l group of functions.

e.g.

```
_locale_t locale = _create_locale( LC_NUMERIC, "C" );
_sprintf_l( pszValue, "%f", locale, 3.141 );
_free_locale(locale);
```

This is thread-safe. The locale can be stored in a static variable to avoid creating it every time you need to format a value.