# SQL Server CAST / CONVERT to numeric culture specific

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, internationalization

Coming from an Oracle background I cannot believe how SQL Server is giving me such a hard time for such a trivial concern.

I only want to parse numbers from a `varchar` column into a numeric column. The thing is, numbers are not in US style but German style format. That means, the decimal mark and digit group separator are interchanged.

Example:

```
1.767,13 equals one thousand and seven hundred ...
```

I kind of looked through every MSDN article. `CAST` doesn't accept any additional parameters. `CONVERT` can take a *style* which though seems to only apply for date/time and money conversion. Further I found `TRY_PARSE` which takes a *culture* parameter but doesn't seem to be available yet in the 2008 version.

I came up with a kludge solution, but that cannot be it!

```
cast(replace(replace([TOTALVALUE],'.',''), ',','.') as numeric(20,2))
```

First the digit group separators get removed and then the decimal mark gets changed from comma to dot. It works, but is it robust etc.

Thanks for comments and answers!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545575/how-can-i-convert-text-with-a-localized-number-format-into-a-number-in-ms-sql-se

Comment: `TRY_PARSE` is a new SQL Server **2012** feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint but yes,

```
cast(replace(replace([TOTALVALUE],'.',''), ',','.') as numeric(20,2))
```

is the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

for completeness - [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213316.aspx) is a link to the MSDN documentation for PARSE, w/code samples and a table of the culture strings, i.e. 'en-US' for US English, 'de-DE' for German, etc...

Answer (score 0):

sorry that this won't help you yet, but SQL Server 2012 has a culture aware `PARSE` function